# Any problems to recreate a BigQuery table used to consume all events from PubSub

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I currently have a `BigQuery` table with all the `PubSub` messages from one `PubSub` topic.
I have no partitions and no clusters currently, but I would like to have them.

I now can recreate the table, but I am not sure if this leads to data loss. Can someone help me what the consequence would be?

I know I can create a table to archive everything, but I want to know the underlying behavior.